# MAC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, android-studio, vim, android-emulator

I'm having the problem that I can't start an emulator in android studio.

I get these errors:

```
20:06   Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

20:06   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I read that I need to change something in `vim ~/.bash_profile`. I tried it but it didn't work. It currently looks like this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/jonas/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

Please note that I don't have any idea what `vim ~/.bash_profile` does or what I have changed in it lol.

I also tried uninstalling the emulators and android studio itself but it didn't work. Can I maybe clean something to complete the whole android sdk?

btw I'm on Mac.

Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I saw all the posts about updating your bash, but it seemed you should be able to set that from within Android Studio.

Preferences > System Settings > Android SDK

One of the items in this pane lists the file system path to the android SDK, typically in your home directory (user folder).  There may also be \ a list of SDK versions supported, such as Android Q, Android Pie (version 9), etc.

The first time I added an emulator I tried oreo and got the PANIC error.

I created a new one, and used Q, which according to the list i described was installed (the others, including oreo were not)

When I launched the emulator, I got my 'Hello World' example app.

So I think that if you are creating an emulator, it needs to be in sync with what you have installed.

Answer (score -1):

you need to define your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_AVD_HOME.

1. open your terminal and type `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add this 2 line and change {your user} by your current
   user :

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/{your user}/Library/Android/sdk
 export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/ryadahitdep/.android/avd`
 
 3. CMD + S to save your changes